# Modal element wont scroll down when bumped off top of the screen

Tags: html, sass, modal-dialog

So I have a modal element that when populated by user generated data becomes to large, vertically, to fit on the screen. I can scroll down to view the content without a problem after setting "overflow-y: auto" but if i resize the window, vertically, and the modal is pushed off the top of the screen, i cant scroll it back down so that the top of it is visible. This seems like it should be an easy fix, but for the life of me , that fix has eluded me.

here is the code from my applications SASS file:

```
.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: rgba($black, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 10%;

  &-container {
    margin-top: 10%;
    position: relative;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: $light-color;
    color: $white;
  }

  &-content {
    padding: 5rem;
  }

  &-p-heading {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }

  &-paragraph {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  &-image-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  &-image {
    height: 7rem;
    width: 10rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    transition: all .25s;

    &-large {
      width: 90%;
      height: 60%;
    }

    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.25);
      z-index: 1000;
    }
  }

  &-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5rem;
    right: 0.5rem;
    transition: all 0.25s;

    &:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

and here is a link to a codepen i made that replicate the behavior:

https://codepen.io/jonas-matlock/pen/abOVYwd

again, to see the problem that i am trying to address, shrink the window vertically from the bottom up to put the top portion of the modal out of view...

Answer (score 1):

All I did was change `margin-top: 10%` to `margin: auto`

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by applying the `center` value to the `align-items` property. According to CSS Flexible Box Layout Module Level 1:

> center<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-align-items-center)</sup>
>
> The flex item’s margin box is centered in the cross axis within the line. (If the cross size of the flex line is less than that of the flex item, **it will overflow equally in both directions**.)

Therefore, you can use the `safe` value, instead:

> safe<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#valdef-overflow-position-safe)</sup>
>
> If the size of the alignment subject overflows the alignment container, the alignment subject is instead aligned as if the alignment mode were start.

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: safe center; /* ADD safe keyword */
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.modal-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h1>I am modal</h1>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or use auto-margin instead of `justify-content`, `align-items` property.

```css
.modal {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.modal-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin: auto; /* ADD */
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h1>I am modal</h1>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
      <p>I am modal content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that only Firefox currently supports the `safe` keyword ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_align-self_flex_context_safe_unsafe)).